# convert python scraping code in PHP to scrape instagram

Tags: php, python, regex, instagram

so here is working code of python to scrape the images from instagram

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json, re, requests

user = 'thefatfoxcamden'

profile = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + user

with requests.session() as s:
s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'

end_cursor = ''
for count in range(1, 3):
    print('PAGE: ', count)
    r = s.get(profile, params={'max_id': end_cursor})

    data = re.search(r'window._sharedData = (\{.+?});</script>', r.text).group(1)
    j    = json.loads(data)

    for node in j['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['media']['nodes']: 
        if node['is_video']:
            page = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/' + node['code']
            r = s.get(page)
            url = re.search(r'"video_url": "([^"]+)"', r.text).group(1)
            print('VIDEO:', url)
        else:
            print('IMAGE:', node['display_src'])

    end_cursor = re.search(r'"end_cursor": "([^"]+)"', r.text).group(1)
```

Code is working awesome now i want to convert this code in PHP

what i can get is right now that i can get only first loop

which code is below

```
<?php

function scrape_insta($username) {
    $insta_source = file_get_contents('http://instagram.com/'.$username);
    $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
    $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]);
    $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
    return $insta_array;
}

 //Supply a username
 $my_account = 'thefatfoxcamden';
 $results_array = scrape_insta($my_account);
 $image_array= array();

  $dataList = ($results_array['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']);


 for($i=0; $i<count($dataList); $i++){
  if($dataList[$i]['node'][__typename]=='GraphImage'){
    //echo '<img src="'.$dataList[$i]['node']['display_url'].'"></br>';
    echo '<img src="'.$dataList[$i]['node']['thumbnail_src'].'"></br>';

   }
}
```

above code is calling only for once

i want to call in loop 3 times like the python code is doing.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can run a python script using php just like this, So you don't have to convert whole python code. Just do this.

```
  <?php system('python filename_with_path.py') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. let me try. i want to do on godaddy server

Comment: > Only our Deluxe, Premium, Unlimited, or Ultimate Linux Web or Classic hosting accounts support Python. https://www.godaddy.com/help/can-i-use-python-272-with-my-hosting-account-7254?